# Why does the glossary needs to be in main?

Tags: glossaries

Here is my example:
https://www.overleaf.com/4991048ykdwjy

I was wondering, why must I put the use package, the input and the makeGlossairies in my main file?

Why can't I just put them in a file with all my settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to keep the glossary entries in the main file -- they can be defined in any file, loaded with `\loadglsentries`

Even `\makeglossaries` can be written in another file, as long as this file is `\input` before the document body, however, I prefer `\makeglossaries` in the real document preamble.

`foosettings.tex`

```
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foo}{%
  name=foo,
  description={This is a foo}
}

\newglossaryentry{bar}{%
  name=bar,
  description={This is a bar}
}
```

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}


\input{foosettings}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Used loadglsentries in the \input and now it works! Thanks

Comment: @VincentGagnon: That's what I said -- reading the manual helps ;-)

Comment: Tip: put `\makeglossaries` before the entry definitions, just in case any of them contain the `see` key. (Doesn't make a difference otherwise, but it's best to get into the habit in the event you add cross-references.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Thanks for the tip: I've changed the order